# Angular 2 - back button on browser preserving the values of the fields

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

This scenario:

Page#2 had a form (with no form controls) with 3 input boxes.

After I click on the submit button, this goes to Page#2 using the router navigation.

Ok, so far, everything is fine. However when the user click on the back button (or history.go(-1), he wish to see the values on the input boxes, but it's disappears when you go back to page#1 by pressing the back button.

**Any idea about how to preserve the form in case where the user decides to use the back button ?**

ty !

Comment: when user clicks back button values will disappear as the routed component will be reinitialized, If you need them to be persist you have to write your own logic to preserve and use.

Comment: If you store them on submit, you could use a GET call and ngOnInit() when they return to the previous page?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. The real scenario is a bit more complex. the textboxes is fact are type ahead that's query the database. But it's okay , guys. Looks like I will need to rewrite it. ty !

Comment: The clearing of unsaved values when navigating away from a URL is by design. You can use guards to prevent navigation away until the values are saved or the user has chosen to discard the values. You could temporarily (automatically) store the values on the server, in cookies, or in local storage. However, retaining values in a form which has gone out of scope is "unusual" and is probably not a best practice.